# Overflow error with load_svmlight_file() from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svmlight

I've created a SVMlight file with only one line from a pandas dataframe:

`from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file

dump_svmlight_file(toy_data.drop(["Output"],       axis=1),toy_data['Output'],"../data/oneline_pid.txt", query_id=toy_data['EventID'])`

The result in the file looks like this:

```
0 qid:72048431380967004 0:1440446648 1:72048431380967004 2:236784985 3:1477 4:26889 5:22 6:36685162242798766 8:1919947 10:22 11:48985 12:1840689
```

When I try to load the file with `query_id=True` I get an overflow error.

```
train = load_svmlight_file("../data/oneline_pid.txt", dtype=np.uint64, query_id=True)
```

OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

If I load the file with `query_id=False` there appears no error message but the value for the query_id is wrong. This is the output:

```
[[       1440446648 72048431380967008         236784985              1477
              26889                22 36685162242798768                 0
            1919947                 0                22             48985
            1840689]]
```

`72048431380967004` appears now as `72048431380967008`.

How do I avoid this error, the maximum value of `np.uint64` is `9223372036854775807` so there should be no overflow error.

Have tried to load with `np.int64` as data type too, but the output is the same.

Scikit-learn version: 0.16.1
OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: Can you open an issue on github? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues Include your OS and scikit-learn version.

Comment: Yes, I will open an issue on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overflow error was fixed for newer scikit-versions.

Comment: The issue is not fixed. Please see my post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848932/sklearn-load-svmlight-file-overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-lo